# PyTorch Dataloader bucket by tensor length

Tags: pytorch

I've been trying to create a custom Dataloader that can serve batches of data that are all same-sized to feed into a Conv2d layer for classification purposes.
Here's some test data
`X` is a `NUMBER OF POINTS x CHOICES x NUM_FEATURES`, while `y` is the label (that can be any integer `CHOICES-1`)

I'm having trouble writing the Sampler and Dataloader.

```
import random
import torch
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from typing import Sequence, Iterator
import numpy as np
sample_probs = np.array([2.04302017e-03, 6.84249612e-03, 3.18776004e-02, 6.69332322e-01,
       1.79056125, 1.63388916, 1.31819391, 1.43798623,
       2.44057406, 5.51664089e-01, 9.66624185e-02, 1.67495225e-02,
       3.59960696e-03, 2.43216687e-05])

X = []
y = []

train_datasets = []

i_dict = {0: 19,
 1: 63,
 2: 30,
 3: 6192,
 4: 16564,
 5: 15115,
 6: 12195,
 7: 13303,
 8: 22578,
 9: 5103,
 10: 894,
 11: 155,
 12: 33,
 13: 2}
for i in range(2,16):
    temp_x = []
    temp_y = []
    for j in range(i_dict[i-2]):
        temp_x.append(torch.rand(i, 4, 1))
        temp_y.append(torch.tensor(random.randint(0,i-1)))
    X = torch.stack(temp_x)
    y = torch.stack(temp_y)
    train_datasets.append((X.clone(),y.clone()))

class WeightedBucketSampler(torch.utils.data.Sampler):
    def __init__(self, data, weights: Sequence[float], num_samples: int,
                    replacement: bool = True, generator=None, shuffle=True, drop_last=False):
        
        super().__init__(data)
        
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.drop_last = drop_last
        self.weights = torch.as_tensor(weights, dtype=torch.double)
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.generator = generator
        self.buckets = defaultdict(list)
        '''data is a CustomDataset containing a tensor of COUNT x NUM_ROUTES x FEATURES x 1 and a tensor with the corresponding labels'''
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.buckets[i+2] += [data[i][0],data[i][1]]
            counter += len(data[i][0]) 
        self.length = counter    

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        # Choose a bucket depending on the weighted sample
        rand_bucket = torch.multinomial(self.weights, self.num_samples, self.replacement, generator=self.generator).tolist()[0]     
        shifter = sum([len(self.buckets[i+2][0]) for i in range(rand_bucket)])
        # Generate random indices from the bucket
        rand_tensor = torch.randperm(len(self.buckets[rand_bucket+2][0]), generator=self.generator)

        yield from torch.add(rand_tensor, shifter).tolist()
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.routes = dict()
        self.choice = dict()
        
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i][0])):
                self.routes[counter] = data[i][0][j]
                self.choice[counter] = data[i][1][j]
                counter += 1
            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.choice)
        
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choice[idx]
        routes = self.routes[idx]
        return routes, choice  

train_datasets_ds = CustomDataset(train_datasets)
bucket_sampler = WeightedBucketSampler(train_datasets, sample_probs,len(sample_probs), shuffle=True, drop_last=False)
loader = DataLoader(train_datasets_ds, sampler=bucket_sampler, batch_size=32, pin_memory=True) 

for X,y in loader:
    print(X.size(),y.size())
```

This code is a combination of [WeightedRandomSampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#WeightedRandomSampler) and [Bucket sampling code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/46176)
I'm essentially sampling via the sample weights of each classification to choose a bucket, and from that bucket choose randomly to form a batch up to `batch_size`.
However, when going through `loader`, I get the output:

```
...
torch.Size([32, 10, 4, 1]) torch.Size([32])
torch.Size([32, 10, 4, 1]) torch.Size([32])
torch.Size([32, 10, 4, 1]) torch.Size([32])
torch.Size([18, 10, 4, 1]) torch.Size([18])
```

The sum of all these batches add up to the elements in bucket 10. So it's right, but it's not jumping to another bucket. Rerunning the code

```
for X,y in loader:
    print(X.size(),y.size())
```

will produce another bucket's batches.

I'm still learning PyTorch, so some of the code might be inefficient. Would love some advice as well!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help on the unofficial PyTorch Discord channel (sudomaze), I've fixed my problem. There's a need to iterate through all the data in the sampler.

The `__len__` function in the sampler also needed fixing.

```
class WeightedBucketSampler(Sampler[List[int]]):
    def __init__(self, data, weights: Sequence[float], num_samples: int,
                    replacement: bool = True, generator=None, shuffle=True, batch_size=32, drop_last=False):
        
        super().__init__(data)
        
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.drop_last = drop_last
        self.weights = torch.as_tensor(weights, dtype=torch.double)
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.generator = generator
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.buckets = defaultdict(list)
        '''data is a CustomDataset containing a tensor of COUNT x NUM_ROUTES x FEATURES x 1 and a tensor with the corresponding labels'''
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.buckets[i+2] += [data[i][0],data[i][1]]
            counter += len(data[i][0]) 
        self.length = counter    

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        # Choose a bucket depending on the weighted sample
        rand_bucket = torch.multinomial(self.weights, self.num_samples, self.replacement, generator=self.generator)   
        
        batch = [0] * self.batch_size
        idx_in_batch = 0
        for bucket_idx in rand_bucket.tolist():
            bucketsample_count = 0
            shifter = sum([len(self.buckets[i+2][0]) for i in range(bucket_idx)])
            # Generate random indices from the bucket and shift them
            rand_tensor = torch.randperm(len(self.buckets[bucket_idx+2][0]), generator=self.generator)
            # print(len(self.buckets[bucket_idx+2][0]), len(rand_tensor.tolist()))
            for idx in rand_tensor.tolist():
                batch[idx_in_batch] = idx+shifter
                idx_in_batch += 1
                if idx_in_batch == self.batch_size:
                    bucketsample_count += self.batch_size
                    yield batch
                    idx_in_batch = 0
                    batch = [0] * self.batch_size
            if idx_in_batch > 0:
                bucketsample_count += idx_in_batch
                yield batch[:idx_in_batch]
                # The last remaining tensors are added into one batch. Terminate batch and move to next bucket
                idx_in_batch = 0
                batch = [0] * self.batch_size
                continue

        
    def __len__(self):
        return (self.length + (self.batch_size - 1)) // self.batch_size

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.routes = dict()
        self.choice = dict()
        
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i][0])):
                self.routes[counter] = data[i][0][j]
                self.choice[counter] = data[i][1][j]
                counter += 1
            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.choice)
        
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choice[idx]
        routes = self.routes[idx]
        return routes, choice  
w = np.array([len(i[0]) for i in train_datasets])
sample_probs = 1/sample_probs*w
train_datasets_ds = CustomDataset(train_datasets)
bucket_sampler = WeightedBucketSampler(train_datasets, sample_probs,len(sample_probs), shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=False)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_datasets_ds, batch_sampler=bucket_sampler)
```